# How to properly create a virtual machine for Windows?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to use Ubuntu but I need Windows for my studies (for like Visual Studio and other stuff does work only under Windows) so I was thinking of making Ubuntu my primary OS and then creating a virtual machine with oracle VirtualBox.

I tried dual booting but I had problems with permissions. When I can read/write on Windows, Ubuntu doesn't have even read permissions and vice versa.

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20423/virtualbox-host-ubuntu-vs-windows-xp and http://askubuntu.com/questions/251165/ubuntu-as-main-os-windows-on-virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest there are five stages of using both Ubuntu and Windows. Here is the list of the five stages in chronological order from the first stage to the last stage. As a new Ubuntu user you are still at stage 1 in the list.

1. New Ubuntu user runs Windows in a virtual machine so that he can pop back into Windows any time it's necessary. Oracle VirtualBox is a good choice for the virtual machine application.
2. Ubuntu user with more experience uses Windows less frequently and wants more RAM to be available in Windows, so he dual boots Ubuntu alongside Windows.
3. Experienced Ubuntu user learns that there are many alternatives to the applications that he used in Windows including running the same Windows applications in Ubuntu using Wine, but he saves his dual boot Windows OS for when he needs to run applications that can't be replaced or won't run in Ubuntu using Wine.
4. The user doesn't use Windows much anymore, so he removes Windows and installs it on another computer if possible.
5. User rarely boots the computer that has Windows on it, and the computer sits unused gathering dust.

Comment: i think i may be between first and second stage .. im new ubuntu user but i still need more RAM to be available in windows ..

Comment: User wishes dell supplied Ubuntu machines so he doesn't pay a windows license just to format it

Comment: Two things worth knowing before you start: 1) For a dual boot, it is always easier to install Windows first before Ubuntu 2) If your computer came with Windows 8 preinstalled, it will have a UEFI firmware interface instead of BIOS, so there are special rules for installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.

Comment: i think i dont have a UEFI firmware .. i desactivated it and work in legacy mode instead (well if memory serves me coz it's been a while since last time i checked my setup ) i tried to install windows first than ubuntu it worked all was fine but yet the permissions were really a problem .. i cant even install new drivers on windows ..

Comment: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) is the best question to start with and if you have any questions that aren't answered there, then the answer may be found in another question or else you will need to ask a new question if your question has not been answered before. Windows drivers do not work in Ubuntu and Ubuntu drivers do not work in Windows, so you need to install the Windows drivers in Windows and the Ubuntu drivers in Ubuntu.